# Front-popping a Java String

Tags: java, string

Having read the documentation of Java's String class, it doesn't appear to support popping from front(which does make sense since it's basically a char array). Is there an easy way to do something like

```
String firstLetter = someString.popFront();
```

which would remove the first character from the string and return it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A String in Java is immutable, so you can't "remove" characters from it.

You can use [`substring`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to get parts of the String.

```
String firstLetter = someString.substring(0, 1);
someString = someString.substring(1);
```

Comment: Good mention of immutable.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily implement this by using `java.lang.StringBuilder`'s `charAt()` and `deleteCharAt()` methods. `StringBuilder` also implements a `toString()` method.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is something like that (even because strings can't be changed - a new one needs to be created), but You can use `charAt` and `subString` to implement your own.

An example of charAt:

```
String aString = "is this your homework Larry?"; 
char aChar = aString.charAt(0);
```

Then subString:

```
String anotherString = aString.substring(1, aString.length());
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `aString.length()` rather than `aString.length() - 1`?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if the string is 10 chars long isn't the index of the last char 9?

Comment: Yes, but the end index in String.substring(int, int) is exclusive. (See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: You can also use just `aString.substring(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to have the String in a FIFO stack? For that you can use a [`LinkedList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which offers under each a [`pop()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop%28%29) method to pop the first from the stack.

To get all characters of a `String` in a `LinkedList`, do so:

```
String string = "Hello World";
LinkedList<Character> chars = new LinkedList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) chars.add(string.charAt(i));
```

Then you can pop it as follows:

```
char c = chars.pop();
// ...
```

**Update**: I didn't see the comment that you'd like to be able to get the remaining characters back as a string. Well, your best bet is to create and implement your own `StringStack` or so. Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class StringStack {
    private String string;
    private int i;

    public StringStack(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public char pop() {
        if (i >= string.length()) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty");
        return string.charAt(i++);
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (i >= string.length()) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is empty");
        return string.substring(i, string.length());
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
String string = "Hello World";
StringStack stack = new StringStack(string);
char c = stack.pop();
String remnant = stack.toString();
// ...
```

To make it more solid, you can eventually compose a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at a [StringReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html). The read() method returns a single character.

Comment: I don't think that will work if I want to keep the remaining data as String and StringReader doesn't appear to have anything like asString().